# design pattern to pass an argument to a jquery deferred task

Tags: jquery, promise

Trying to get my head around deferred tasks. Is it legit to make the following function a promise?  I want to take action not as soon as the ajax call has resolved --that would be premature-- but when the UI element has been fully populated with the data returned by the ajax call. There's a loop in the success callback.

```
function populateCitiesDropdown( state ) {

    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    // ajax call to get cities for the specified state
    // ...
    // (removed)
    // ...

    url:  "GetCitiesForSpecifiedState?state=" + state,

    // ...

    }).success ( function ( result, b, c) {

        // loop through result data
        //  populate Cities SELECT element
        // resolve when loop is finished
        dfd.resolve();

    });

    return dfd.promise();

}
```

How to pass the `state` parameter to the **populateCitiesDropdown** function when using `$.when( ...` ?

```
$.when( populateCitiesDropdown ).done( function () ...
```

EDITS (additional background):

There are multiple dropdowns that need to be populated with data returned by multiple ajax calls.  Each task consists of an ajax data fetch AND a SELECT being populated.  If I simply pass the ajax call to $.when:

```
              $.when(ajax1, ajax2, ajax3).done( function () { foo() ; });
```

then function foo() executes prematurely, i.e. before the SELECT elements are populated. The ajax calls resolve before the code inside their success callbacks executes.

When all of the dropdowns have been populated (which occurs some time AFTER all of the ajax requests have resolved) then I will issue a BindMainRecordtoUI call.

Comment: `$.when( populateCitiesDropdown )` does not do what you expect. Just use `populateCitiesDropdown(…).then(…)`!

Comment: Also, don't use the [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) in your `populateCitiesDropdown` function. With the ajax call, you do already have a promise.

Comment: @Bergi, but I want the action to occur not when the ajax fetch is complete, but when the SELECT ui element is populated with the data returned by the ajax call.

Comment: So? Just [chain that action after the ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) and return a promise for the populated select elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for anything more complicated than this:

```
$.when( populateCitiesDropdown(xxx) ).done( function () ...
```

Remember `$.when()` doesn't take a callback function.  It takes a promise.  So, you have to actually call and execute the `populateCitiesDropdown` function (and can pass it any arguments you want when doing so) and it returns the promise that is immediately passed as an argument to `$.when()`.  This is different than the `.done()` or `.then()` handlers which are indeed callbacks which will be called by the promise code at some later time.

Also, keep in mind that if you only have one promise, there is no reason to use `$.when()` as you can just put the `.done()` directly on the returned promise.

```
populateCitiesDropdown(xxx).done(function() {...});
```

The purpose of `$.when()` is in managing multiple promises at once, not just one.

---

Also, there's really no reason to create a new deferred.  jQuery is already returning a promise from the ajax call so you can just use that one:

```
function populateCitiesDropdown( state ) {

    return $.ajax({...    

    // ajax call to get cities for the specified state
    // ...
    // (removed)
    // ...

    url:  "GetCitiesForSpecifiedState?state=" + state,

    // ...

    }).then ( function ( result, b, c) {

        // loop through result data
        //  populate Cities SELECT element
        // resolve when loop is finished

    });

}
```

And, you should switch to `.then()` instead of `.success()` as `.success()` is deprecated and `.then()` is the standard promise way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple promises -- a half dozen dropdowns. Didn't realize I could pass the argument inside the when (   ).

Comment: @Tim: Actually you *need to*, otherwise you will get a promise for a function and no ajax call is made.

Comment: @Tim - OK, fine to use `$.when()` if you have multiple promises.  I also added a simplification for your `populateCitiesDropdown()` function.  No need to create your own deferred there.  Just use the one that jQuery already returns.

Comment: @jfriend00:  I like your `return .ajax(...` and will do some more testing tomorrow when I'm back in the office. I wasn't getting expected results when chaining a `.then(...` in which I updated the UI element in a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but your implementation could be improved (there are many other ways to do the same thing; this is just an example).

```
function populateCitiesDropDown(state) {
  var defer = $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
    $.get('GetCitiesForSpecifiedState', { state: state })
      .done(function (data) {
        // do stuff with returned data
        dfd.resolve('populateCitiesDropDown: loaded');
      })
      .fail(function () {
        dfd.resolve('populateCitiesDropDown: server error');
      });
  });

  return defer.promise();
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
populateCitiesDropDown('TX').done(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: There's really no reason to create another deferred here when you can just use the one that's already returned from the jQuery ajax.

Comment: I think you guys are misunderstanding my question.  The resolution I'm awaiting is not the completion of the ajax call, but the completion of the loop that populates the SELECT UI element with data returned by the ajax call. When the dropdowns are all populated, then I want to bind the main record to the UI. Binding the main record to the UI must wait until the dropdowns are ready.

Comment: I don't see how my data-binding function would know when your "do stuff with returned data" task had finished.

Comment: @Tim - they would be chained `.then()` handlers and they execute in sequence.  The second one calls its callback when the first one returns.  That's how promises work.  If the first one returned a promise (which you aren't doing here), then the second chained `.then()` handler wouldn't be called until that new promise was itself resolved (not a complication you have to know here, but yet another feature of chained `.then()` handlers).

Comment: @Tim I assume that adding the state cities to your select UI is a sequential `for` loop, right? So...you resolve the promise, `dfd.resolve()` after the loop finishes, which is what my example illustrates.